# Custom loss function access tensor channels

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a 2-channel numpy array of shape (64, 64, 2) as input to my CNN.
I want to build a customized loss function as described in https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate :

```
def basic_loss_function(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.abs(y_true - y_pred))

model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss=basic_loss_function)

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=3)
```

But I want to something more complicated that this basic one. What I need is to do an inverse DFT (ifft2d) and my y_pred and y_true are expected to be each of shape (64,64,2), with the 2 channels being the real and imaginary parts of a fft2. How can I access correctly the y_pred and y_true channels (which are some kind of keras/tensor layer I guess?) to rebuild a complex number in the form **RealPart+1j*ImagPart** (in numpy it would be y_pred[:,:,0] and y_pred[:,:,1] ) ?

--> In summary, does someone know exactly what kind of object is y_pred and y_true and how to access their channels/elements? (This is not easy to debug since would need to be run in a compiled CNN, so better know it beforehand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`y_true` and `y_pred` are Tensors of shape `(batchsize, ...[output shape]...)`. Your input has shape `(64,64,2)` but I'm not sure what your output looks like, if your output is indeed `(64,64,2)` then `y_pred` or `y_true` have shape `(64,64,64,2)` given your `batchsize=64`.

Dealing with Tensors is very much like numpy's syntax so You can use slice notation with tensors e.g., `y_true[:,:,:,0]` (note the added batch dimension).

Tensorflow has functions for computing DFT,FFT,..etc. See [tf.signal](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/signal) and [tf.signal.rfft2d](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/signal/rfft2d)

If your loss function involves operations on the input, not just the outputs `y_true` and `y_pred`, then you can use `model.add_loss` instead of `model.compile(loss= basic_loss_function)` as follows

```
x = Input(shape=(64,64,2))
y_true = Input(shape=...))
# your CNN layers
y_pred = Dense(128)(net)

model = Model(input=[x, y_true], output=y_pred)
model.add_loss(basic_loss_function(x, y_true, y_pred))
```

note that the labels (aka `y_true`) is now an input to the model.

Comment: great thanks, it does work. I have another question now ... since I m using tf2.1.0 my generators don't work anymore... in case you're interested :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60583696/data-generators-with-tf2-1-0

Comment: I have implemented it, but have some problems... mind looking at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60590403/custom-keras-tf-loss-function-with-fft2d-ifft2d-inside-does-not-work

Comment: @MohamedEzz Looks like you're using `output`, but never defined it. Can I safely assume that's a typo and you meant `y_pred`?